# How do I set the dash-to-dock width?

Tags: dash-to-dock

In Ubuntu 21.04, I can set the dash-max-icon-size to something smaller than the default 48. This shrinks the icons, and the vertical space occupied by each icon. However, it does not shrink the width of the dock, leaving a lot of blank space on the left and right of each icon in the dock.
Is there a way to shrink the dock width to match the icons in the dash?